# Can't save Advanced Custom Fields date field via AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've tried a bunch of formats but can't update my acf DATE(birthday) field via ajax. Every other field updates fine. Is my structure wrong?

```
{
  "post_title": "Add User",
  "email": "add@test.com",
  "birthday": "2013-08-25T09:00-12:00",
  "phone": "123-123-1234",
  "notes": "hello notes",
  "address": "250 Ramsey Junction 123aa"
}
```

Comment: I've also tried $dob = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $updated2 = update_field('field_58b80f51fd87a', $dob, $post_id); with no luck

Comment: I was able to get it by passing this string: 20170310